# 550 /bin/ls -lgA : Not enough space

Tags: ftp

We run Wu-ftpd 2.6.2-6 on our AIX6.1TL09. After a crash in the AIX level, system was rebooted and after that Wuftp is presenting the following error message, when I issue 'dir' or ls "any argument" during a ftp session: 
550 /bin/ls -lgA : Not enough space.

The weirdest thing is that we clone (via mksysb) another brother system, which wuftp is running properly. Even using this technique, the problem persists. And we also re-installed wu-ftp from scratch, which indicates the problems is not on AIX nor in the wu-ftp binaries.

This error is preventing our application to work properly as it depends on the output of the "dir" command.

Does anyone had this problem before or has an idea where to troubleshoot?

Some facts:

- if I issue just 'ls' during the ftp session, I don't get an error.
- This is not a filesystem space problem.
- This is not a permission or ownership problem.
- This is not a swap full situation
- This can happen to all user ids, anytime, no matter if it is jailed, or where its home is mounted on.
- There are no Software or Hardware errors on the HMC.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find this error string in the wu-ftpd source code. However it looks like a message from the AIX system, so I suspect a system error when trying to get some more virtual memory page allocated. lsps, ps and the like could be useful to troubleshoot such memory issues.